# Assistance needed: Keyboard navigation in ExtJS GridPanel - GroupingView

Tags: extjs, keyboard, gridpanel, ext.net

I'm currently working on converting my public facing ExtJS (actually Ext.NET) app to allow keyboard navigation with clear focus indication. So far I've managed to get a TabPanel, and a basic GridPanel (almost) working, with a custom re-work of the ExtJS theme CSS, and some keynav listeners.

Now I've come to a GridPanel with a GroupingView on it and found that the Group headings don't seem to gain focus or be able to attain keyboard selection.

Has anyone any pointers on how I can get the Group Titles selectable, and then hook on a key handler to expand/contract the group?

Thanks, 
AndyPC!

ps If it helps, my app can be found [here](http://www.bristol.gov.uk/my-neighbourhoods?postcode=bs66sb) (querystring variable added so you don't have to find a valid postcode):

Comment: Have you asked this question on Ext.NET Forum?